# Global Variable Changing Property of Json Object

Tags: json, vb.net

I want to create a global json variable, but when I do it's properties change. .count is no longer valid, instead it has 'length'

```
Dim objJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BFEventList)(strCatalogue)

    Dim lps
    For lps = 0 To objJson.result.Count - 1
```

for a local var it works fine, but when i make it global, result.count is no longer a valid property. Is there a simple reason for this? Or a better way of creating it as a global var?

```
GlobalVariables.objJsonBFEventData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BFEventMarketList)(strCatalogue)

    Dim lps
    For lps = 0 To GlobalVariables.objJsonBFEventData.result.Count - 1
```

with this declared below. It fails on the above line as .count is no longer valid

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared objJsonBFEventData
End Class
```

if i create locally and pass to the global var it works ok for some reason

```
Dim objJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BFEventMarketList)(strCatalogue)
    GlobalVariables.objJsonBFEventData = objJson
    Dim lps
    For lps = 0 To GlobalVariables.objJsonBFEventData.result.Count - 1
```

So it's working, but not sure why....